# Creating shim OSGi bundle or mapping bundle names

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle, equinox

Long time ago somebody has created OSGi bundle named `org.apache.commons_logging` and used it with `Require-Bundle` all over the place. Now it is baked in everywhere. I want to update the Commons Logging library without having to repackage it to change the original `org.apache.commons.logging` symbolic name. Other 3rd party bundles expect bundle symbolic name without the underscore. Now, I do not want to have two exactly same bundles with just slightly different symbolic name.

- Is it possible to create some sort of shim bundle named `org.apache.commons_logging` that would just import everything the official `org.apache.commons.logging` bundle exports and it would reexport it?
- Is it possible to do this using some clever Maven plugin that would help me with such task? Unfortunately, Commons Logging is not the only affected bundle here.

I am using Apache's `maven-bundle-plugin`, usually, and we are developing with Eclipse's Equinox OSGi implementation.

**UPDATE**

`Require-Bundle: org.apache.commons.logging;visibility:=reexport` might be the solution. Am I right?